# How to disable spell-checking in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Recent Notepad++ started to come with spell checking which puts "*red lines that appear under misspelled words*" (ms office help terminology) mainly in txt files. I'd like to disable it everywhere.

#### motivation

I would like to disable this feature for several reasons:

- (usability-obstacle) (eye-strain) the red lines get in the way while reading text. 
  (In particular if you suffer from vision impairment, dyslexia or
  other reading difficulties, you may want this to be *off*.)
- (unwelcome feature) arguably, it can be considered ill-positioned/unnecessary to make it a mandatory feature
- I do not need it
- (privacy) I'm not comfortable with the idea that yet-another piece of code is reading my writings 
  (diary, anyone?) - you can call me paranoid but in today's word I wanna keep this at minimum. 
   **edit:** actually, [it has already been exploited](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/32706/).

#### what I've tried

I've tried looking around in `(menu bar)` -> `settings` -> `preferences...` but the option, should it exist, eluded me.

I've also tried going to `(menu bar)` -> `plugins` -> `plugin manager` -> `show plugin manager` -> `(tabs)` -> `installed`, search `spell-Checker` and uninstall (`Remove`) it. But the lines are still underlined with red. :(

**How do I disable spell-checking in Notepad++?**

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest 1-click solution: **the toolbar button**.

[image]

The spell checking is disabled in all documents. The setting is persistent after reopening files and restarting Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

there are a couple of methods to do this.

To completely remove the spell checker functionality, go to:

```
Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager > "Installed" (Tab) > Select DSpellCheck and Remove
```

To disable it, you can go to:

```
Plugins > DSpellCheck > Untick the box which is titled "Spell Check Document Automatically"
```

Alternatively, you can enable or disable spell checking for certain file types.  For this, you go to:

```
Plugins > DSpellCheck > Settings
```

From here, you can choose to exclude *.txt or similar or set it to only spellcheck types like *.html if you do any web work..  whatever works for you really!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice there is *another* spell-check plugin called `DSpellcheck`. It was the one!

Just go to `Plugin Manager`'s `installed` tab, **tick** `DSpellCheck` and click `Remove`. It  will restart your notepad++ and it will be gone.

### Step-by-step (inside Notepad++)

- save your work!
- go to `(menu bar)` -> `plugins` -> `plugin manager` -> `show plugin manager` -> `(tabs)` -> `installed`
- search `DSpellCheck`, **tick** it, and click `Remove`.
- **warning:** Notepad++ will restart!
- it should be gone!

### history and security

`DSpellCheck` seems to be [included from Notepad++ 6.3.3 and onwards](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.3.html):

> Release Date: 2013-05-05
>
> [...]
>
> Notepad++ v6.3.3 new features:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Add new spell checker plugin (DSpellCheck).

It already seems to have a record of being exploited in the past: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/32706/

Comment: Question was about how to disable the functionality, not about how to remove the plugin

Comment: @smc yes you're right.  downvote's maybe a bit harsh for it though :D it's your vote of course, I'm not complaining, but you could *upvote the question* if you have the interest ;). accepted the other answer.

Comment: @naxa - I won't downvote this answer because its a good answer but the question itself is a exact duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound not my day. I really did check. what gives.. :) oh noes, the duplicate has 119 votes, mine has -1... clumsy jealousy, hey it's not the day. :D important thing it's now off. thanks for pointing out the dup.